# Authentication via login dialog in Scout (RAP)

Tags: eclipse-rap, eclipse-scout

I'd like to have an authentication based on scouts default security concept found in https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Concepts/Security.

**What I've done:**

I added the `BasicSecurityFilter` to the servers `plugin.xml`:

```xml
<extension name="" point="org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.commons.filters">
      <filter aliases="/ /process /remotefiles /updatesite" class="org.eclipse.scout.http.servletfilter.security.BasicSecurityFilter" ranking="30"></filter>
</extension>
```

And activated it in the `config.ini`:

```
org.eclipse.scout.http.servletfilter.security.BasicSecurityFilter#active=true
org.eclipse.scout.http.servletfilter.security.BasicSecurityFilter#realm=Development
org.eclipse.scout.http.servletfilter.security.BasicSecurityFilter#users=TEST\=admin
```

On client side I added the `InternalNetAuthenticator` in the `plugin.xml`:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.core.net.authenticator">
    <authenticator class="org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap.login.internal.InternalNetAuthenticator"</authenticator>
</extension>
```

And set it as default authenticator in the client `Activator`:

```java
@Override
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
  super.start(context);
  plugin = this;
  InternalNetAuthenticator authenticator = new InternalNetAuthenticator();
  InternalNetAuthenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
}
```

**What happens:**

- `BasicSecurityFilter.negotiate()` is called when accessing the application (first load, e.g. `http://localhost:8015/web`)
- `InternalNetAuthenticator.getPasswordAuthentication()` is called when the negotiation in the `BasicSecurityFilter` fails (this is when user and password are not found in the HTTP header, or user and password are invalid).

  - Opening a Dialog on RAP level (see `InternalNetAuthenticator.showModalDialog(status, display)`) is impossible, because Display.getDefault() or Display.getCurrent() always returns `null`.

    - This is because all UI operations (e.g. opening a dialog) MUST appear in the UIThread (see java-doc in `Display.getDefault()`).
    - The `InternalNetAuthenticator` is *instantiated* in the UIThread (see `Activator.start()`), but it isn't *called* in the UIThread! **Why???**
  - Returning a `PasswordAuthentication` object provides the credentials within the HTTP header to the next `BasicSecurityFilter.negotiate()` call.
- `BasicSecurityFilter.negotiate()`is called again with the given credentials.

**What fails:**

So because of the fact, that the `InternalNetAuthenticator.showModalDialog(status, display)` isn't called in the UI-thread, it causes a `NullPointerException`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap.login.internal.InternalNetAuthenticator.showModalDialog(InternalNetAuthenticator.java:102)
...
```

**What I've already considered:**

- General information

  - `https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/HowTo/3.9/Extending_the_login_dialog`
  - `https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Concepts/Securit`
- UI-thread problem

  - `https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/440290/`
  - `https://www.eclipse.org/rap/developers-guide/devguide.php?topic=threads.html`
  - I already tried to store the UI-thread when instantiating the Authenticator in the `Activator.start()` method by creating an own Authenticator and adding a parameter to the constructor like:

    - `MyAuthenticator my_authenticator = new MyAuthenticator(Thread.currentThread());`
    - But this causes an `IllegelStateException` or something like that. So the UI-thread is not accessible on this way.
  - Using the `BasicSecurityFilter` on RAP-level (in `plugin.xml` of the RAP bundle) makes it possible to use the systems default login dialog.

    - But I would like to have a custom SecurityFilter which have acces to other server side systems, so it must appear on server side and a RAP/client side SecurityFilter is no option!

**Summary**

All I can see is, that solving the Problem with the UI-thread will be the preferred way to move this issue forward.

I'll also accept alternative solutions to have a custom login dialog in my eclipse-scout-RAP environment.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem description:**

If I've understood your use case correctly, you'd like to introduce something like a form-based authentication. I guess this is what you wanted to achieve with displaying the login dialog in the RAP UI-Thread.

**Solution proposal:**

Some steps were taken to introduce a form-based authentication to the Scout demo application BahBah chat that can be found at [1]. Please note that this example was based on an older Scout version (3.10).
In the following explaination, the implementation in [1] will be referred:

In [1], the approach was to make use of the facility of the Tomcat webcontainer to achieve a form-based authentication.
A sample HTML login page [2] can be found in the RAP UI bundle under the folder web-resources.
Therefore, in the plugin.xml [3] of the RAP application, the servlet filter BasicForwardSecurityFilter was removed. Make sure that the web-resources are accessible, e.g. under /res.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.resources">
  <resource alias="/res" base-name="/web-resources"/>
</extension>
```

In the RAP application web.xml file the following entries were made.

```
<!-- Activate form-based authentication -->
<login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <realm-name>BahBahJAASLogin</realm-name>
  <form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/res/index.html</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/res/index.html</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<!-- Define security role to access the application -->
<security-role>
  <role-name>BahBahRolePrincipal</role-name>
</security-role>

<!-- static resources under /res/* should be accessible without requiring authentication --> 
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>All Access</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/res/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    <http-method>PUT</http-method>
    <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
    <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
    <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<!-- Protect all other URLs of the application -->
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Protected Resources</web-resource-name
    <url-pattern>/web/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/tablet/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/mobile/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>BahBahRolePrincipal</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<!-- Define security filter and mapping --> 
<filter>
  <filter-name>BahbahSecurityFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.bsiag.securityfilter.BahbahSecurityFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>BahbahSecurityFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The BahbahSecurityFilter ensures that only authenticated principals are allowed to access the protected resources on the UI server. 
In the doFilter method, the check is done by calling a method like:

```
// Taken from org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.commons.authentication.ServletFilterHelper#isRunningWithValidSubject(HttpServletRequest) see [4]
public boolean isRunningWithValidSubject(HttpServletRequest req) {
  String username = req.getRemoteUser();
  if (username == null || username.isEmpty()) {
    return false;
  }

  Subject subject = Subject.getSubject(AccessController.getContext());
  if (subject == null || subject.getPrincipals().isEmpty()) {
    return false;
  }

  for (Principal principal : subject.getPrincipals()) {
    if (username.equalsIgnoreCase(principal.getName())) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

In BahBahChat, a Realm [5] and a login module are configured to authenticate the users.
In particular, UserPrincipal and RolePrincipal are defined and also a LoginModule class is created.

In the Tomcat context.xml file the realm is configured.

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm"
       appName="BahBahJAASLogin"
       userClassNames="com.bsiag.securityfilter.BahBahUserPrincipal"
       roleClassNames="com.bsiag.securityfilter.BahBahRolePrincipal"/>
```

Finally, the jaas.config file is defined:

```
BahBahJAASLogin  {
  com.bsiag.securityfilter.BahBahJAASLoginModule required debug=true;
};
```

The BahBahJAASLoginModule implements for the actual authentication process. A good example of setting up JAAS authentication in Tomcat can be found at [6]

Please also have a look at the Eclipse Scout forum post [7] that summarizes the necessary steps in a more generic way.

- [1]
  https://github.com/BSI-Business-Systems-Integration-AG/org.eclipsescout.demo/tree/features/kle/formBasedAuthentication
- [2] `org.eclipsescout.demo.bahbah.ui.rap/web-resources/index.html`
- [3] `org.eclipsescout.demo.bahbah.ui.rap/plugin.xml`
- [4]
  http://git.eclipse.org/c/scout/org.eclipse.scout.rt.git/tree/org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.commons/src/main/java/org/eclipse/scout/rt/server/commons/authentication/ServletFilterHelper.java?h=releases/5.2.x
- [5] https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html
- [6]
  http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/jaas-authentication-in-tomcat-example
- [7]
  https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=821196&goto=1435976&#msg_1435976